# In NSScrollView the vertical slider always points to bottom of the view

Tags: cocoa

I am developing Mac app. In this app, I am using a NSScrollView's instance as scrollView.
And I have set a customView which is an instance of NSView in this ScrollView as:

```
[scrollView setDocumentView:customView];
```

But, the NSScrollView's vertical Slider always points to the bottom of the view as:
[image]

I want that the slider always points to the top of the custom View as:

[image]

How can I make this change?
Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by setting the scrollToPoint property of ScrollView's ContentView.
Here is the code:

```
[[scrollView verticalScroller] setFloatValue:0.0];
[[scrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, y)];
// here y = (difference b/w scrollView's content size height and scrollView's height)
```