# NSScrollView position is always bottom

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, interface-builder, nsscrollview

I am writing an installer plugin and due to the amount of information on screen I need to use a NSScrollView. The issue is that now the default position of the scroller is at the bottom when I would like it at the top.

How can I set the scrollers default position to be top.

Comment: You problem is similar to this question [NSScrollView the vertical slider always points to bottom ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873712/in-nsscrollview-the-vertical-slider-always-points-to-bottom-of-the-view